# Bockstein homomorphism for $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and "Steenrod" $n$th power

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology, spectral-sequences, research

The Bockstein homomorphism can be generalized for $\mathbb{Z}_n$ values, $$\beta_n:
H^m(M^d,\mathbb Z_n) \to H^{m+1}(M^d,\mathbb Z_n),$$
and
$$\beta_n x =\frac1n d x  \text{ mod } n,$$ 
$$x \in  H^m(M^d,\mathbb Z_n),$$
$$\beta_n x \in  H^{m+1}(M^d,\mathbb Z_n).$$

> When $n=2$ for $\mathbb{Z}_2$, we can study the relation between Bockstein homomorphism and Steenrod square.
>
> For general $\mathbb{Z}_n$, can we find any meaning between this Bockstein homomorphism and "Steenrod" $n$th power?

Is there such an "Steenrod" object to represent the $\beta_n x$?

Comment: If you read about the Steenrod algebra, you'll find that when $p$ is an odd prime, there are some relations between the Steenrod powers $P^n$ and the Bokstein homomorphism. These are called the Adem relations.

Comment: Thanks. This is the related case for Bockstein homomorphism and Steenrod square: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2113909/ 

What is the $n$ in your set-up?

Comment: @Jack Davies, do you mean Adem relations or Adams relations?